# matplotlib can not import pylab

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have installed `matplotlib` and of course its requirements `Numpy` and `scipy` on my pc but I get this error message when I import `pylab`:

```
   >>> from matplotlib import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 230, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/finance.py", line 36, in <module>
    from matplotlib.dates import date2num
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/dates.py", line 137, in <module>
    import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
  File "anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 138, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/_path.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString
```

As far as I remember it used to work but now I get error message. I even re-installed it but didn't help. How could I fix it?

Comment: @MrE why does matplotlib have conflict with `PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString`?

Answer (score -1):

It may be that you are missing:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
```

However, if that does not work. Reinstall the Anacoda distribution, then make sure you have numpy and scipy installed.

The top of your program is then:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib as mpl
import pylab
```